# Can not get response from API on heroku

Tags: node.js, api, express, heroku, https

I have made a Node.js application which fetches data from a api
'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPin?pincode=823003&date=21-06-2021 It works totally fine on localhost but when I deployed it on heroku it doesn't get the response. I am using free tier on heroku.
This is my console
[Heroku CLI logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr4mu.jpg)

This is my code

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require('https');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

function join(t, a, s) {
   function format(m) {
      let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', m);
      return f.format(t);
   }
   return a.map(format).join(s);
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
  let options = [{day: '2-digit'}, {month: '2-digit'}, {year: 'numeric'}];
  let today = join(new Date, options, '-');
  let pin = req.body.pin;
  const email = req.body.email;
  let centers = "";
  console.log(pin);

  const cowin_endpoint = 'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPin?pincode=' + pin + '&date=' + today;
  https.get(cowin_endpoint, (response)=>{
    response.on('data', (data)=>{
      const x = JSON.parse(data);
      // console.log(x);

      let i = x.sessions.length;
      (x.sessions).forEach((sess)=>{
          var centerDetails = "NAME:- " + sess.name + "\nADDRESS:- " + sess.address + "\nVACCINE:- " + sess.vaccine + "\nAGE:- " + sess.min_age_limit + "+\nDOSE1:- " + sess.available_capacity_dose1 + "\nDOSE2:- " + sess.available_capacity_dose2;
          centers += centerDetails + "\n\n";
      })


      var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: process.env.MAIL_ID,
          pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
      });

      var subject = "There are " + i + " vaccination centers near your area."

      var mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.MAIL_ID,
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        text: centers
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
      });


      // console.log(centers);
    })
  })
  // res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
  res.send("Successfully sent !")
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=>{
  console.log("Server is up and running..");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error log says that "x.sessions" in line 34 is undefined.
Use an if statement to check whether "x.sessions" is undefined.

And by the way, blur out your email form the error log!

Comment: "x.sessions" is undefined in this case but when i run it locally it works completely fine.

Comment: As I don't have access to your config variables I can't try that code snippets on my machine. Try logging variables in the console and also see if your environment variables are set.